# Check to see if one year has passed

Tags: mysql, ruby, datetime, time

I run a web design firm, and we also sell hosting on a yearly basis to our customers. I'm writing a Ruby script to read all of the customers from a MySQL database and check to see if a year has passed. If it has (or is at least close to expiring), I want it to send an Email to them.

I have the Emailing part down, but how would I check to see if one year has passed using the Time class, or another solution based in SQL?

(looking back with this edit, it seems as though I don't quite know the SQL needed, so any help on that is appreciated)

Comment: Wouldn't you be doing that in the SQL?

Comment: year has passed and close to expiring are two different conditions. Are you looking for two queries

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail - Please elaborate on how I would do this.

Comment: @GhostRider - It appears to be that I am.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to solve this issue using ruby you can use `>>` when dealing with a `Date` to increment it by `N` months (such as *11*, which will give your customers some time to deal with the payment).

When you've got this incremented date you should compare it to what the current date is to see if it's less or equal (ie. the date is in the past), if so; send out your email.

```
>> (Date.strptime('2012-07-07') >> 11).to_s
=> "2013-06-07"

>> if (Date.strptime('2011-06-15') >> 11) < DateTime.now
>>   print "More than 11 months has passed!"
>> end
More than 11 months has passed!=> nil
```

---

Though, you are much better of solving this issue directly in the *SQL query*, which would boil down to something as the below:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldN
FROM `customers_table`
WHERE ADDDATE(last_payment, INTERVAL 11 MONTHS) <= NOW ()
```